# Add Tumblr Like Button to non-Tumblr Page?

Tags: tumblr

Is it possible to add a button like the nice one done by ThinkingStiff in the example [here](http://like-button.tumblr.com/) ?

That one is designed to be used *on* Tumblr pages. I'd like to get the same functionality on a page that is *outside* of Tumblr.

Yes, I already have a method to get the `{ReblogURL}` and the `{PostID}` values it needs.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ThinkingStiff This one's for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, solved myself. Just replace `{ReblogURL}` and `{PostID}` in original code:

```
<div class="my-like" data-reblog="{ReblogURL}" data-id="{PostID}" title="Like"></div>
```

with the new vars (from whichever method you use to get them) and replace that div.

Example:

```
<div class="my-like" data-reblog="3Pbn6aNA" data-id="12345678901" title="Like"></div>
```

**Note**: Those vars are not a live Tumblr post.